# Collection Variable Question

Tags: c#, generic-collections

Lets say that I have a generic collection in the string format. I want to extra the values to a label how would I go about doing that ive tried a few things ive read on here but cant seem to get it to work.

```
List<string> listcollection= new List<string>();

....Populate Collection Here....

MsgLabel.Text = Controls[string.Format(("MyInts: {0}", listcollection[1].Text));
```

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: The code doesn't compile and I don't know what you're trying to do anyway. You want to "extra" the values to a label? Maybe you should clean up the code and the question.

Comment: Always strive to post compilable code, but in this case where you're specifically wondering how to write the code, be 100% clear about what the intended result is. In this it is hard to tell exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Al Keep Try adding the letters 'ct' to the end of 'extra', and I think you'll find that - whoa! - it turns out the question is in English, after all. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's multiple ways to understand your question:

- You want to extract the 2nd value and place it in the label, as shown in the example
- You want to combine all the values into a list (MyInts is plural)

---

### Extract 2nd value

```
MsgLabel.Text = string.Format("MyInts: {0}", listcollection[1]);
```

---

### To combine them

You're probably looking for [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx).

This would work with the example you've posted:

```
MsgLabel.Text = string.Format("MyInts: {0}", string.Join(", ", listcollection));
```

That code requires .NET 4.0, otherwise `string.Join` requires an array, so if you're not on 4.0, the following code is what you need:

```
MsgLabel.Text = string.Format("MyInts: {0}", string.Join(", ", listcollection.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating generic collection of strings you should not call "Text" property collection[idx].Text. Just use .Join or extract particular element from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine all the strings (and it seems to me like you wanna do that), you can do something like:

```
List<string> listcollection = new List<string>();
string myText = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < listcollection.Count; i++) {
   myText += ("string no. " + (i - 1).ToString() + ": " + listcollection[i] + Environment.NewLine);
}
MsgLabel.Text = myText;
```

or use `,` instead of `Environment.NewLine` if you want to split it by `,`

EDIT: See the comment of Lasse V. Karlsen for a quicker solution. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: See [this method: Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) for a way to do it without the loop: `string.Join(", ", listcollection.Select((s, i) => "string no. " + (i + 1) + ": " + s))`